# Kobe 1980 AJP “Derivation of Maxwell’s equations from the gauge invariance of classical mechanics”. Confusion between field and source locations

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-mechanics, gauge-invariance

In his paper (Kobe 1980 AJP “Derivation of Maxwell’s equations from the gauge invariance of classical mechanics”) Kobe writes down a new Lagrangian, Eqn (2.10) using the definitions of charge and currrent densities - (2.7) and (2.8) - and the total time derivative of $\Lambda$(**r**,t), (2.9). A problem I am having is that up to that point $\Lambda$ is a function of **r** and t with **r** being the displacement vector of the source particle with a charge, q. In (2.10) Kobe seems to make $\Lambda$ a function of **x** which is the displacement vector of the field point.

Can someone able to explain to me the missing steps which allow the author to switch the independent variable of $\Lambda$ inside the integral in (2.10)?

Here's a detailed working-out following the suggestion from @Laff70.

The new Lagrangian starting from (2.5) is,

$$L_0^{'}=L_0+\frac{q}{c}\frac{d\Lambda(\mathbf x,t)}{dt}$$
$$       =L_0+\frac{q}{c}\left(\frac{\partial\Lambda(\mathbf x,t)}{\partial t}+\dot{\mathbf x}\bullet\frac{\partial\Lambda(\mathbf x,t)}{\partial \mathbf x}\right)$$
$$       =L_0+\frac{1}{c}\left(q\frac{\partial\Lambda(\mathbf x,t)}{\partial t}+q\dot{\mathbf x}\bullet\frac{\partial\Lambda(\mathbf x,t)}{\partial \mathbf x}\right)$$
$$       =L_0+\frac{1}{c}\left[\left(\int{\rho({\mathbf x},t) dx^3}\right)\frac{\partial\Lambda(\mathbf x,t)}{\partial t}+\left(\int{\mathbf J(\boldsymbol x,t)} dx^3\right) \bullet\frac{\partial\Lambda(\mathbf x,t)}{\partial \mathbf x}\right]$$

In the working-out I have used the explicit dependence of $\Lambda$ on ${\mathbf x}$ and t.

The problem I didn't describe more clearly earlier in my question is that in the last line both the time-derivative, $\frac{\partial\Lambda(\mathbf x,t)}{\partial t}$ and the gradient, $\frac{\partial\Lambda(\mathbf x,t)}{\partial \mathbf x}$ are functions of $\mathbf x$, the field displacement vector. This means they can't be taken inside the integrals which are with respect to field points ($dx^3$).

Hope I have described my problem more clearly now. If you, @Laff70 or anyone else has helpful suggestion I would be very grateful to hear it.

Thank you.

P.S. Not knowing how physics.stackexchange works I have edited my initial question. I used this as "comment" doesn't seem to allow insertion of MathJax symbols. Please let me know if I have breached any rule that applies to this forum.

Answer (score 0):

The function $Λ(\vec{x},t)$ is a function which is defined for all points $\vec{x}$ in space at time $t$. In terms of its value, it's really only interesting at the point $\vec{r}$ where the particle is at. Same can be said about the charge density and current density functions. It seems they initially introduced Λ as defined with $\vec{r}$ to make the form of (2.9) clearer. Using it with any $\vec{x}$ is equally valid though, which is why it's used like that in the volume integral. Hope this clarified things.

Comment: I have elaborated my original question. Hopefully it clarifies the problem.